# Code 39 barcode colon character, C# pattern

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, code39

I am working on a C# project involving Code 39 barcode generation. I have been tasked with trying to add a colon character ":".

I'm not very knowledgeable on this stuff, hence the question, I've done some research on this, and am a little confused.

From what I've read, Code 39 is restricted to 43 characters. I believe I have all of these characters and their associated C# patterns here:

```
static Dictionary<char, Pattern> codes;

    static Code39 ( ) {
        object[][] chars = new object[][] 
        {
            new object[] {'0', "n n n w w n w n n"},
            new object[] {'1', "w n n w n n n n w"},
            new object[] {'2', "n n w w n n n n w"},
            new object[] {'3', "w n w w n n n n n"},
            new object[] {'4', "n n n w w n n n w"},
            new object[] {'5', "w n n w w n n n n"},
            new object[] {'6', "n n w w w n n n n"},
            new object[] {'7', "n n n w n n w n w"},
            new object[] {'8', "w n n w n n w n n"},
            new object[] {'9', "n n w w n n w n n"},
            new object[] {'A', "w n n n n w n n w"},
            new object[] {'B', "n n w n n w n n w"},
            new object[] {'C', "w n w n n w n n n"},
            new object[] {'D', "n n n n w w n n w"},
            new object[] {'E', "w n n n w w n n n"},
            new object[] {'F', "n n w n w w n n n"},
            new object[] {'G', "n n n n n w w n w"},
            new object[] {'H', "w n n n n w w n n"},
            new object[] {'I', "n n w n n w w n n"},
            new object[] {'J', "n n n n w w w n n"},
            new object[] {'K', "w n n n n n n w w"},
            new object[] {'L', "n n w n n n n w w"},
            new object[] {'M', "w n w n n n n w n"},
            new object[] {'N', "n n n n w n n w w"},
            new object[] {'O', "w n n n w n n w n"},
            new object[] {'P', "n n w n w n n w n"},
            new object[] {'Q', "n n n n n n w w w"},
            new object[] {'R', "w n n n n n w w n"},
            new object[] {'S', "n n w n n n w w n"},
            new object[] {'T', "n n n n w n w w n"},
            new object[] {'U', "w w n n n n n n w"},
            new object[] {'V', "n w w n n n n n w"},
            new object[] {'W', "w w w n n n n n n"},
            new object[] {'X', "n w n n w n n n w"},
            new object[] {'Y', "w w n n w n n n n"},
            new object[] {'Z', "n w w n w n n n n"},
            new object[] {'-', "n w n n n n w n w"},
            new object[] {'.', "w w n n n n w n n"},
            new object[] {' ', "n w w n n n w n n"},
            new object[] {'*', "n w n n w n w n n"},
            new object[] {'$', "n w n w n w n n n"},
            new object[] {'/', "n w n w n n n w n"},
            new object[] {'+', "n w n n n w n w n"},
            new object[] {'%', "n n n w n w n w n"}
            //new object[] {':', "n w n n n n n n n"}
        };

        codes = new Dictionary<char, Pattern> ( );
        foreach ( object[] c in chars )
            codes.Add ( (char)c[ 0 ], Pattern.Parse ( (string)c[ 1 ] ) );
    }
```

I've also read though that there is a "Full ASCII code 39" that includes more characters and these characters are represented by two sequences of code 39 characters. Here is the reference page where I've learned most of this: [Code 39 Barcode Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Full_ASCII_Code_39)

In the case of the colon character, the two code 39 characters that represent it are "/" and "Z" or "/Z".

My question is, what is the C# pattern {n w n n etc.} for the colon character? Also, am I just overthinking this, is the colon character really not supported? Any and all detail you can provide is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why are you not using a `Dictionary<char,string>` ? Is there some kind of reason to use object arrays in 2018?

Comment: @PatrickArtner a Dictionary<char, string> is being built, I have updated the code to provide more detail.

Comment: `:` is not defined in code39 https://www.dafont.com/code39.font